# What is the English word for the role of a person who betrays his master's attitudes?

Tags: single-word-requests

A Polish diplomat gave Catherine the Great a little dog, then, by observing the little dog, he found out who was Catherine's secret lover.

In a hierarchical organization, people who are two layers above you always look nice, but the ones appointed immediately above you always betray their masters' attitudes.

I wonder if there is an English word for this role played by little dogs.

Thanks,

Comment: Clever little dog. Is there a word for this in some other language that you are aware of?

Comment: 狗腿子 in Chinese (a dog's leg), often used to say that there is no need to hit back at the one who offended you because he is just a  dog's leg.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand completely. Is the implication that you can judge a master by his minions?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox - Yes. Once upon a time, a young lady tried to avenge her BF on me, but her dog was so friendly to me, her whole scheme was ruined.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that 'one's lieutenants betray the leader's true intentions' is the same as 'a dog's leg/no need to retaliate against someone so unimportant'? THose don't seem comparable at all to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Something like the Clever Hans. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans#The_Clever_Hans_effect

Comment: There is a saying, "You can judge a man by the company he keeps." but that's not quite what you're looking for I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a noun to describe the dog itself, the idiomatic **[dead giveaway](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+giveaway)** serves your purpose quite well:

> Something that reveals a fact or an intention completely. The car in the driveway was a dead giveaway that someone was at home.

Alternatively, just **[giveaway](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/giveaway)** can be sufficient:

> Something that reveals a fact that was meant to be concealed. (Often with dead.) The way he was walking was a giveaway to the fact that he was the one who was injured.

This particularly emphasises the idea that the fact was intended to remain hidden.